Make the '& element' itself centred, not the largest equation centred and the '& elements' aligned in the align* environment
More easily described with an example, below I've attatched some latex and an image produced inside texstudio that can hopefully illustrate my point being made. The "Hence Proved" text hopefully shows how the & element, in this case "=" isn't centred, which is my desired goal
I've left an image of which on the top is what my code is getting me and the bottom of what I wish to achieve. I've also attatched an overleaf document below with my preamble along with the code in question
https://www.overleaf.com/read/fsfcwzrdkxkf#7adb34
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{apcr}&=bq\\
    apcr&=b^2q^2\\
    apcr&=\left( \frac{a+c}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{2pr}{p+r}\right)^2\\
    (pr)(ac)&=\left( \frac{a^2+c^2+2ac}{4}\right)\left(\frac{4[pr]^2}{p^2+r^2+2pr}\right)\\[5pt]
    \frac{\cancel{pr}}{\left(\lfrac{4[pr]^{\cancel{2}}}{p^2+r^2+2pr}\right)}&=\frac{\left( \ufrac{a^2+c^2+2ac}{4}\right)}{ac}\\[5pt]
    \frac{p^2+r^2+2pr}{4pr}&=\frac{a^2+c^2+2ac}{4ac}\\[5pt]
    \frac{p^2+r^2}{pr}+\frac{2pr}{pr}&=\frac{a^2+c^2}{ac}+\frac{2ac}{ac}\\[5pt]
    \frac{p^2+r^2}{pr}+\cancel{2}&=\frac{a^2+c^2}{ac}+\cancel{2}\\
    \frac{p^2}{pr}+\frac{r^2}{pr}&=\frac{a^2}{ac}+\frac{c^2}{ac}\\
    \frac{p}{r}+\frac{r}{p}&=\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\\
\end{align*}
\vspace{-1.5cm}
\begin{nscenter}
    \underline{\underline{Hence Proved}}
\end{nscenter}



please always provide a small test document so people can see the issue and test answers, not fragments especially ones using non standard environments such as nscenter for which no definition is given. In general it's not possible to centre the = as one side or the other will over-print the margins but you have given no indication of page size, perhaps it is possible in this case.

Please extend your code fragment to MWE (Minimal Working Example). Where is defined `\lfrac?. As I observe, your system of equation is quit fairly centered.

I've updated my post to hopefully make my desired solution more clear & attached a document with my preamble which defines various custom environments, but for what it is worth I don't believe any of them have any weight to my question. I am a bit new to latex, so your help & patience are both very appreciated

it really helps if you provide an example here. If you don't think the custom examples are relevant to the question, don't use them in the example. Do not use links to other sites , your question here is archived forever and the code at that link may change or vanish.

Thanks for all the additional advice David Carlisle, I'll be sure to regulate my posts on stack exchange to be appropiate from hereon out


The easiest way is simply to add a row with equally large left and right sides, then back up more to hide it. This does as you ask and centers the & which is the left hand side of the = . If you want to centre on the centre of the = you can adjust widths slightly, but I wouldn't.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,cancel}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{apcr}&=bq\\
    apcr&=b^2q^2\\
    apcr&=\left( \frac{a+c}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{2pr}{p+r}\right)^2\\
    (pr)(ac)&=\left( \frac{a^2+c^2+2ac}{4}\right)\left(\frac{4[pr]^2}{p^2+r^2+2pr}\right)\\[5pt]
    \frac{\cancel{pr}}{\left(\frac{4[pr]^{\cancel{2}}}{p^2+r^2+2pr}\right)}&=\frac{\left( \frac{a^2+c^2+2ac}{4}\right)}{ac}\\[5pt]
    \frac{p^2+r^2+2pr}{4pr}&=\frac{a^2+c^2+2ac}{4ac}\\[5pt]
    \frac{p^2+r^2}{pr}+\frac{2pr}{pr}&=\frac{a^2+c^2}{ac}+\frac{2ac}{ac}\\[5pt]
    \frac{p^2+r^2}{pr}+\cancel{2}&=\frac{a^2+c^2}{ac}+\cancel{2}\\
    \frac{p^2}{pr}+\frac{r^2}{pr}&=\frac{a^2}{ac}+\frac{c^2}{ac}\\
    \frac{p}{r}+\frac{r}{p}&=\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\\
\end{align*}
\vspace{-1.2cm}
\begin{center}
    \underline{\underline{Hence Proved}}
\end{center}

\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{apcr}&=bq\\
    apcr&=b^2q^2\\
    apcr&=\left( \frac{a+c}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{2pr}{p+r}\right)^2\\
    (pr)(ac)&=\left( \frac{a^2+c^2+2ac}{4}\right)\left(\frac{4[pr]^2}{p^2+r^2+2pr}\right)\\[5pt]
    \frac{\cancel{pr}}{\left(\frac{4[pr]^{\cancel{2}}}{p^2+r^2+2pr}\right)}&=\frac{\left( \frac{a^2+c^2+2ac}{4}\right)}{ac}\\[5pt]
    \frac{p^2+r^2+2pr}{4pr}&=\frac{a^2+c^2+2ac}{4ac}\\[5pt]
    \frac{p^2+r^2}{pr}+\frac{2pr}{pr}&=\frac{a^2+c^2}{ac}+\frac{2ac}{ac}\\[5pt]
    \frac{p^2+r^2}{pr}+\cancel{2}&=\frac{a^2+c^2}{ac}+\cancel{2}\\
    \frac{p^2}{pr}+\frac{r^2}{pr}&=\frac{a^2}{ac}+\frac{c^2}{ac}\\
  \frac{p}{r}+\frac{r}{p}&=\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\\
  \hspace*{.4\textwidth}&\hspace*{.4\textwidth}\\
\end{align*}
\vspace{-1.7cm}
\begin{center}
    \underline{\underline{Hence Proved}}
\end{center}
\end{document}


appreciate it very much!
